# Using SpEL and eval to call a controller method

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I was wondering if it was possible to call a controller method using the  tag from a JSP page, a bit like the way it's done in JSF.

**My Controller**

```
@Controller(value="planesController")
@RequestMapping({"/planes"})
public class PlanesController {

    @Autowired
   private PlanesDAO planesDAO;

   public List<Plane> allPlanes(){

      return planesDAO.getAll();
}
```

**My JSP**

```
<sf:form>
    <s:eval expression="planesController.allPlanes()" var="planes" />

    <sf:checkboxes items="${planes}" path="planes"  id="avions"/>

</sf:form>
```

**I keep getting the exception :**

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Field or property 'planesController' cannot be found on null
```

I know I can use model.addAttribute but I call this method from several JSP pages and I thought one of the of the  tag was to allow access to beans from views.

I'm using Spring 3.0.5

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The answer was provided on [forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?104736-Using-SpEL-and-eval-to-call-a-controller-method): use `<s:eval expression="@planesController.allPlanes()" var="planes" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Letting the view call controller code is just plain wrong, no matter if it works or not. This is MVC backwards.

It would be better if you write a service to do what you want to do and give your view access to that service, but you'd still violate MVC. It would be even better to do all of these calls in your controller in the first place and pass the resulting model to the view without any service calls there.